# Applying lags to data without loop

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr

Let's consider following data set:

```
library(plm)
data("EmplUK", package = 'plm')
df <- EmplUK[1:6]
head(df)
> head(df)
  firm year sector   emp    wage capital
1    1 1977      7 5.041 13.1516  0.5894
2    1 1978      7 5.600 12.3018  0.6318
3    1 1979      7 5.015 12.8395  0.6771
4    1 1980      7 4.715 13.8039  0.6171
5    1 1981      7 4.093 14.2897  0.5076
6    1 1982      7 3.166 14.8681  0.4229
```

As you can see it's basic panel data. Now I want to apply lag to this data set, but of course I don't want to apply lags to firm and year.

Now let's define lag vector as `lags <- c(2,1,3,0)`. It means that:

(1) Two lags for sector (Third variable in data frame)

(2) One lag for emp (Fourth variable in data frame)

(3) Three lags for wage (Fifth variable in data frame)

(4) Zero lags for capital (Sixth variable in data frame)

Of course lags have to be applied with respect to convention of panel data - i.e. including lags at the beginning of each period.

**My solution**

```
for (i in seq_len(length(lags))) {
  # Filter our data and apply lags for each time period
  df <- df %>%
    dplyr::group_by_at(1) %>%
    # Take only those observations which amount 
    # is bigger than maximum number of lags
    dplyr::filter(n() > max(lags)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(
      colnames(df)[i + 2], dplyr::lag,
      n = lags[i], default = NA
    ))
}

> head(df)

> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   firm [1]
   firm  year sector   emp  wage capital
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1  1977     NA NA     NA     0.589
2     1  1978     NA  5.04  NA     0.632
3     1  1979      7  5.60  NA     0.677
4     1  1980      7  5.01  13.2   0.617
5     1  1981      7  4.72  12.3   0.508
6     1  1982      7  4.09  12.8   0.423
```

However even though it's working I found it inconvenient - I did it using loop, but I'm certain that it's not necessary over there. Could you please give me a hand in rewriting code I did but without loop ?

Answer (score 1):

One slightly complicated approach would be to use the mutate function over a list of functions.

We can do this by first associating the values with the column names. We can do this in an array as follows `lags <- c(sector = 2, emp = 1, wage = 3, capital = 0)`.

We can then construct a function that takes a column name, a value and a dataframe. This will group the data frame as we want to set the lag for each grouped variable.

Note that we must use some metaprogramming tools in this function to use the column names correctly. See https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html for more details.

In our mutate function we expand out our list of functions with the `!!!` operator using our input arrays. Here we pass make our list of functions using `imap`. `imap()` takes an input array, a function and we can add additional inputs using the `..x` syntax where x is a number.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plm)
data("EmplUK", package = 'plm')
df <- EmplUK[1:6]

# Add list of colnames and values for functions
lags <- c(sector = 2, emp = 1, wage = 3, capital = 0)

# Create function to add lags to column
a <- function(.x, .y, df) {
# Convert colname to variable
  y <- as.name(.y)
  y <- expr(!!y)
  
# Return column with lags
  return(
    df %>% 
      group_by_at(1) %>%
      mutate(!!y := dplyr::lag(!!y, .x)) %>%
      `[[`(.y)
  )
}

# Apply our function to our dataframe using imap
df %>%
  dplyr::filter(n() > max(lags)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(!!!imap(lags, ~a(.x, .y, ..3), .))
#>      firm year sector        emp    wage capital
#> 1       1 1977     NA         NA      NA  0.5894
#> 2       1 1978     NA   5.041000      NA  0.6318
#> 3       1 1979      7   5.600000      NA  0.6771
#> 4       1 1980      7   5.015000 13.1516  0.6171
#> 5       1 1981      7   4.715000 12.3018  0.5076
#> 6       1 1982      7   4.093000 12.8395  0.4229
#> 7       1 1983      7   3.166000 13.8039  0.3920
#> 8       2 1977     NA         NA      NA 16.9363
#> 9       2 1978     NA  71.319000      NA 17.2422
#> 10      2 1979      7  70.642998      NA 17.5413
#> 11      2 1980      7  70.917999 14.7909 17.6574
#> 12      2 1981      7  72.030998 14.1036 16.7133
#> 13      2 1982      7  73.689003 14.9534 16.2469
#> 14      2 1983      7  72.418999 15.4910 17.3696
#> 15      3 1977     NA         NA      NA  7.0975
#> 16      3 1978     NA  19.156000      NA  6.9469
#> 17      3 1979      7  19.440001      NA  6.8565
#> 18      3 1980      7  19.900000 22.6920  6.6547
#> 19      3 1981      7  20.240000 20.6938  6.2136
#> 20      3 1982      7  19.570000 21.2048  5.7146
#> 21      3 1983      7  18.125000 22.1970  7.3431
#> 22      4 1977     NA         NA      NA  8.4902
#> 23      4 1978     NA  26.160000      NA  8.7420
#> 24      4 1979      8  26.740000      NA  9.1869
#> 25      4 1980      8  27.280001 14.8283  9.4036
#> 26      4 1981      8  27.830000 14.8379  8.8939
#> 27      4 1982      8  27.169001 14.8756  8.3905
#> 28      4 1983      8  24.504000 15.2332  7.4351
#> 29      5 1976     NA         NA      NA 22.3804
#> 30      5 1977     NA  86.677002      NA 22.2703
#> 31      5 1978      7  87.099998      NA 25.1670
#> 32      5 1979      7  87.000000 20.6323 25.3515
#> 33      5 1980      7  90.400002 18.2782 28.2394
#> 34      5 1981      7  89.199997 18.1369 25.7959
#> 35      5 1982      7  82.699997 18.1896 20.3681
#> 36      6 1976     NA         NA      NA  0.1694
#> 37      6 1977     NA   0.748000      NA  0.1618
#> 38      6 1978      3   0.766000      NA  0.1499
#> 39      6 1979      3   0.762000 23.1889  0.1458
#> 40      6 1980      3   0.729000 20.5393  0.1468
#> 41      6 1981      3   0.731000 20.9387  0.1412
#> 42      6 1982      3   0.779000 21.7626  0.1261
#> 43      7 1976     NA         NA      NA  0.9934
#> 44      7 1977     NA   1.600000      NA  0.9330
#> 45      7 1978      3   1.650000      NA  0.9650
#> 46      7 1979      3   1.680000 30.8513  0.9629
#> 47      7 1980      3   1.680000 28.5550  0.9224
#> 48      7 1981      3   1.660000 29.8602  0.9992
#> 49      7 1982      3   1.560000 30.5894  0.8802
#> 50      8 1976     NA         NA      NA  4.5486
#> 51      8 1977     NA   9.145001      NA  4.6194
#> 52      8 1978      3  10.855000      NA  5.0373
#> 53      8 1979      3  10.749000 30.9089  4.8748
#> 54      8 1980      3  10.959000 24.4679  3.2221
#> 55      8 1981      3  10.698000 28.0558  2.8343
#> 56      8 1982      3   8.174000 28.7445  1.7506
#> 57      9 1976     NA         NA      NA  0.3824
#> 58      9 1977     NA   2.006000      NA  0.4551
#> 59      9 1978      3   2.656000      NA  0.4529
#> 60      9 1979      3   2.712000 26.0825  0.4524
#> 61      9 1980      3   2.744000 21.9545  0.4676
#> 62      9 1981      3   2.757000 22.8100  0.4810
#> 63      9 1982      3   2.849000 23.3720  0.4753
#> 64     10 1976     NA         NA      NA  1.1293
#> 65     10 1977     NA   3.823000      NA  1.0143
#> 66     10 1978      7   3.935000      NA  1.1169
#> 67     10 1979      7   3.528000 23.3533  1.1626
#> 68     10 1980      7   3.520000 21.3251  1.0827
#> 69     10 1981      7   3.467000 20.9319  1.0636
#> 70     10 1982      7   3.090000 20.4536  1.0958
#> 71     11 1976     NA         NA      NA  0.4099
#> 72     11 1977     NA   1.359000      NA  0.5741
#> 73     11 1978      3   1.346000      NA  0.5563
#> 74     11 1979      3   1.338000 23.0614  0.5145
#> 75     11 1980      3   1.353000 20.2275  0.5895
#> 76     11 1981      3   1.264000 22.1435  0.4847
#> 77     11 1982      3   1.158000 22.5496  0.4359
#> 78     12 1976     NA         NA      NA  0.2569
#> 79     12 1977     NA   1.780000      NA  0.2072
#> 80     12 1978      3   1.643000      NA  0.1999
#> 81     12 1979      3   1.390000 34.2991  0.2007
#> 82     12 1980      3   1.350000 30.3979  0.1473
#> 83     12 1981      3   1.082000 31.1431  0.1158
#> 84     12 1982      3   0.780000 33.3105  0.1036
#> 85     13 1976     NA         NA      NA  0.5785
#> 86     13 1977     NA   2.353000      NA  0.5613
#> 87     13 1978      1   2.386000      NA  0.5273
#> 88     13 1979      1   2.375000 22.3833  0.5180
#> 89     13 1980      1   2.415000 23.0607  0.4608
#> 90     13 1981      1   2.266000 23.4931  0.3750
#> 91     13 1982      1   1.777000 26.0042  0.3147
#> 92     14 1978     NA         NA      NA  0.3902
#> 93     14 1979     NA   3.165000      NA  0.4311
#> 94     14 1980      1   3.096000      NA  0.4228
#> 95     14 1981      1   2.991000 20.9113  0.3810
#> 96     14 1982      1   2.692000 21.8887  0.3051
#> 97     14 1983      1   2.175000 23.7010  0.2041
#> 98     14 1984      1   1.801000 21.3925  0.1685
#> 99     15 1977     NA         NA      NA  1.8498
#> 100    15 1978     NA   7.220000      NA  1.9215
#> ...
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Assign column names to `lags` and then use mutate/across with the indicated function which looks up the corresponding lag in `lags`.

```
library(dplyr)

lags <- c(2, 1, 3, 0)
names(lags) <- tail(names(df), length(lags))

df %>%
  group_by(across(1)) %>%
  filter(n() > max(lags)) %>% 
  mutate(across(names(lags), ~ lag(.x, n = lags[[cur_column()]]))) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do it this way

```r
library(tidyverse)
data("EmplUK", package = 'plm')
df <- EmplUK[1:6]

Lag <- c(0, 0, 2, 1 ,3, 0)
df_split <- group_split(df, firm)

map_df(df_split, ~map2_df(.x, Lag, ~lag(.x, n = .y)))
#> # A tibble: 1,031 x 6
#>     firm  year sector   emp  wage capital
#>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     1  1977     NA NA     NA     0.589
#>  2     1  1978     NA  5.04  NA     0.632
#>  3     1  1979      7  5.60  NA     0.677
#>  4     1  1980      7  5.01  13.2   0.617
#>  5     1  1981      7  4.72  12.3   0.508
#>  6     1  1982      7  4.09  12.8   0.423
#>  7     1  1983      7  3.17  13.8   0.392
#>  8     2  1977     NA NA     NA    16.9  
#>  9     2  1978     NA 71.3   NA    17.2  
#> 10     2  1979      7 70.6   NA    17.5  
#> # ... with 1,021 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem I have with your solution is that it's only adding lags to first observations whereas in panel data we want to have lags at the beginning of each period.